# How to combine some attributes in two rows into one in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table **books** which looks like this:

`___BookTitle______Author
 1. Sample Book   AuthorA
 2. Sample Book   AuthorB`

*Sample Book* has been written by both *AuthorA* and *AuthorB*. I want to combine them to get the following result

`___BookTitle______Author
 1. Sample Book   AuthorA, AuthorB`

I cannot figure out how to do it in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function:

```
SELECT   book_title, GROUP_CONCAT(author SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM     books
GROUP BY book_title
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I wasn't aware of GROUP_CONCAT().

Comment: Accepting your answer because of the SEPARATOR clause.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do the trick,

```
SELECT BookTitle, GROUP_CONCAT(Author)
  FROM books
 GROUP BY BookTitle
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I wasn't aware of GROUP_CONCAT().

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function for this

```
___BookTitle______Author
 Sample Book   AuthorA
 Sample Book   AuthorB
```

QUERY IS

```
SELECT BookTitle, GROUP_CONCAT(Author) 
FROM book GROUP BY BookTitle;
```

Out Put

```
___BookTitle______Author
 Sample Book   AuthorA, AuthorB
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipes, concat operations?? If both are wanted as a simple string. May be table types if expecting as an entity.